# Which of these three options is most efficient for the matrix equation `Wx + b`?

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, machine-learning, neural-network

I'm trying to program a neural net from scratch and I am wondering about the performance of including the bias of each layer inside of the weight matrix for the corresponding layer:

```
# For a single layer i of feed forward:
z = W[i] @ a[i-1] + b[i].reshape(-1,1)
```

as opposed to:

```
z = ((w[i] @ a[i-1]).T + b[i]).T
```

or initialize weights such that bias is included as the last 'column' and each activation matrix gets a row of corresponding ones:

```
ones = np.ones(len(X))
z = w[i] @ a[i-1].append(ones)
```

The reason the question comes up is that if I want `X` to be 2d array containing many samples and many variables, the first code snippet tends to give broadcast errors as I'm trying to add a 1d array to each column of a 2d array (hence the `.reshape(-1,1)`).

I wish SO had LaTeX capability but I hope the above options are clear. If not, please comment and I'll try to expound.

Comment: What are the typical shapes of the variables W, a, and b?

Comment: @Han-KwangNienhuys It's going to be highly variable depending on the depth of the neural network and # of nodes per layer. the shape of `W[i]` will be (m x n) where `m` is the number of nodes in layer `i` and `n` is the number of nodes in layer `i-1`. `b[i]` will always be a row or column vector with length equal to the number of nodes in layer `i`.  The first layer will have a number of nodes corresponding to the number of variables in the sample space (i.e. a matrix of containing measurements of height, weight, and age first layer size of 3. After that the choice of layer sizes is arbitrary.

Comment: Could you give a range for m and n and also specify the shape and range of sizes for a, b, and X? I cannot tell from the code sample whether a is a 1D or a 5D array.

Comment: @Han-KwangNienhuys no array will ever exceed 2d. Everything will be standard linear algebra on matrices (2d) and vectors (1d). For example `b[i]` might have shape (10,) or (20,), `w[i]` and `a[i]` might have shape (5,10) or (100, 35). It's totally arbitrary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In numpy, operations such as `.T` and `.reshape()` are very fast, because they don't move any data around. It's unlikely that there is any performance difference between the first two options. The third option (using `append(ones)`) is something you should generally avoid, since appending to a numpy array results in alloating a new array and copying all the values.

Although `.T` and `.reshape` are fast, there is likely to be some difference depending on whether the original data was stored row-major ('C') or column-major ('F'); see [numpy array docs](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) This will depend strongly on the underlying matrix-multiply code and on whether the arrays (or at least the rows and columns) fit in the cache of the CPU. If you use Anaconda Python, then it's Intel MKL behind the scenes, which is very efficient (as long as you run it on an Intel CPU). Assuming that you use single-precision floats and W is usually not larger than 3500 elements (14 kB of data), the entire array is likely to fit in the L1 cache.

If `a` was a 2D array and you select one row at a time in `a[i-1]`, you use elements of `a` that were sequential in memory if `a` was stored in C order (default for numpy). If you obtain `a` from `aa.T` where `aa` was a C-order array, then the elements in `a[i-1]` would not be contiguous in memory, which would incur extra overhead. I did some testing; it looks like the differences are small (15% for small arrays) in practice; I assume that the matrix library will rearrange the array in memory if necessary.

If you use IPython (in Jupyter Notebook or Spyder), then you can do your own speed tests using e.g.

```
%timeit -n 10 -r 10 a @ b
```

(Use `?timeit` for more information).